# Write binding programmatically

Tags: avaloniaui

I have it in the designer

````
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="blabla" Binding="{Binding uet,StringFormat=0.00;-0.00;#}"/>```
How to write ```
                    string? strf="";
                    var eng = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    if (f.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    { strf = "";}
                    else if(f.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    {
                        strf = ",StringFormat=0;-0;#";
                    }
                    else if (f.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    {
                        strf = ",StringFormat=0.00;-0.00;#";
                    }
                    eng.Header = atrddd.DisplayName;
                    eng.CanUserSort = true;
                    eng.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
                    eng.Binding = new Binding(f.Name+strf);
                    this.list1.Columns.Add(eng);
````

eng.Binding = new Binding(f.Name+strf); => runtime error
Sorry for the translation

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, this is how it's done: var binding = new Binding();
                    binding.StringFormat = strf;
                    binding.Path = f.Name;